# How to detect multiple key down event in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I just got started learning AS3.

Let's say I have two textfields on my sprite.

I like to move textfield 1 when I press left or right arrow keys, but I also want to move textfield 2 when I press space while textfield 1 is moving like...an airplay game (you can shoot a missile while you're moving).

I really like to post my source code...but I actually have no idea where to begin.

the following code moves textfield 1 when I press arrow keys...

my code snippet:

```
private function keyHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{

    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case 38:
            this._txt.y -= 10;
            break;
        case 40:
            this._txt.y += 10;
            break;

        case 39:
            this._txt.x += 10;
            break;
        case 37:
            this._txt.x -= 10;
            break;
    }


}
```

Comment: @Laurent // everything works fine....I think www0z0k already answered my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author www0z0k
     */
    public class KeyExample extends Sprite {
        private var _theyArePressed:Object = { };
        public function KeyExample() {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);         
        }

        private function onUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            _theyArePressed[e.keyCode] = false;
        }

        private function onDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            _theyArePressed[e.keyCode] = true;
            if (_theyArePressed[Keyboard.SPACE] && _theyArePressed[Keyboard.UP]) {
                //do anything
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

but keep in mind that that AFAIK keyboards can handle limited quantity of keys pressed at the same time, depending on the hardware

Comment: FYI, I'd advise you to have a dedicated, reusable key class.

Comment: it's just an example, it should store pairs like `{ keyCodes : [], functionReference : functionName }` and check them `onDown` to be reusable

Comment: @www0z0k would you mind explaining why this is necessary instead of just using bool variables like spacePressed and upPressed?

Comment: @Neal Davis to track other arrow keys (or any other ones if needed) with no need to declare more variables

Comment: Oh! This is excellent! By using an array, we are allowed to put something in an empty array at position 67, or wherever, right? So as you press more keys, it fills the array and each array item can have a value of pressed or not. Thanks.