# How do I make 2 KeyDown functions work independently?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class untitledCode extends MovieClip
    {
        private var speed:Number = 5;
        public function untitledCode()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, whenKey1);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, whenKey2);
        }
        private function whenKey1(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                mcPlayer1.y -=  speed;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 40)
            {
                mcPlayer1.y +=  speed;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 37)
            {
                mcPlayer1.x -=  speed;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 39)
            {
                mcPlayer1.x +=  speed;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 96)
            {
                mcPlayer1.play();
            }
        }
        private function whenKey2(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 87)
            {
                mcPlayer2.y -=  speed;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 83)
            {
                mcPlayer2.y +=  speed;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 65)
            {
                mcPlayer2.x -=  speed;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 68)
            {
                mcPlayer2.x +=  speed;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 90)
            {
                mcPlayer2.play();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

There are 2 MovieClips, mcPlayer1 and mcPlayer2. When I hold a key for one MovieClip and then press a key for another, the first MovieClip stops(and vice versa). How do I make them move simultaneously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect multiple key down event in as3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975668/how-to-detect-multiple-key-down-event-in-as3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975668/how-to-detect-multiple-key-down-event-in-as3) I informed you about that was already on SO, I tested their answer and although it works, there is keyboard lag with their implementation.  So I optimized it using the `ENTER_FRAME` event...

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var speed:Number = 5;
        private var _keyDownStatus:Object = { };

        public function Main()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, keyCheck);
        }

        private function onUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            _keyDownStatus[e.keyCode] = false;
        }

        private function onDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            _keyDownStatus[e.keyCode] = true;
        }

        private function keyCheck(e:Event):void {
            // Player 1 Events
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.LEFT]) {
                mcPlayer1.x -=  speed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
                mcPlayer1.x +=  speed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.UP]) {
                mcPlayer1.y -=  speed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.DOWN]) {
                mcPlayer1.y +=  speed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.NUMPAD_0]) {
                mcPlayer1.play();
            }

            //Player 2 Events
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.A]) {
                mcPlayer2.x -=  speed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.D]) {
                mcPlayer2.x +=  speed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.W]) {
                mcPlayer2.y -=  speed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.S]) {
                mcPlayer2.y +=  speed;
            }
            if (_keyDownStatus[Keyboard.Z]) {
                mcPlayer2.play();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I've tested this in Flash CC 2014 and it works perfectly!  I did change the name of the class in my example for my example to work, so please change it to be whatever class name you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend you do add only one key down event listener and save each pushed key and add a key up event listener to remove, so, you can control when only one key is pressed or multiple keys.

I created a simple example (just to explain the main logic), you should adapt and optimize it for your own needs.

```
    private var keyControl:Vector.<uint>;

    public function Test() 
    {
        keyControl = new Vector.<uint>();

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDownHandler, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUpHandler, false, 0, true);    
    }

    private function onUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        keyControl.splice(keyControl.indexOf(event.keyCode), 1);
    }

    private function onDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        if(!isKeyPressed(event.keyCode)) keyControl.push(event.keyCode);

        /*
        to check if some key is being pressed use 
        if(isKeyPressed(Keyboard.SPACE))
        {
            // do something
        }

        if(isKeyPressed(Keyboard.SPACE) && isKeyPressed(Keyboard.A))
        {
            // do something
        }
         */
    }

    private function isKeyPressed(key:uint):Boolean
    {
        var returnValue:Boolean;
        for (var i:int = 0, numKeys:uint = keyControl.length; i < numKeys; i++) 
        {
            if(keyControl[i] == key)
            {
                returnValue = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```